# General guidelines for defining lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Now that we're able to use C++11 lambdas in our codebase we're grappling with working out the general principles of how they should be defined and used.  I realise that there are certainly subjective elements to this, but I think there are also likely to be some more general rules of thumb that will be useful to the community.

What are the general principles of defining a lambda?

- When should you prefer to capture by reference `[&]` or value `[=]`?  What are the performance implications?
- When should you prefer to capture a variable explicitly, eg `[&foo]` ?
- Under what circumstances should you specify a return type?  (C++14 has better support for inferring return types than C++11)
- How complex can a lambda be before it's better being rewritten as a function?

Personally, my general principle at the moment is *'Use a lambda whenever you need a simple predicate or comparator'*, but this may mean I'm missing out on some much more powerful use cases.

Comment: Also note that lambda expressions enable you to simplify `std::bind` expressions to something a lot more readable.

Comment: @rubenvb: Without C++14, this is more or less dependent on the parameters of the lambda. Bind is already polymorphic, lambdas are not, so you might have to repeat long types in the parameter list while you can use placeholders with bind.

Comment: @ltjax I was primarily thinking of binding more than 1 function in a single lambda, not a single function with a large number of long parameter types.

Comment: Yup, it's a great replacement for those.

Either way, shouldn't this be a community wiki instead?

Comment: Interesting how one of the more subtle capture necessities wasn't mentioned, namely capturing object-context for access member variables within a lambda. Ie. `[this]` is often not-so-obvious to people when the time comes that they need it.

Comment: You should only `[&]` when the lambda will be used, discarded, and not copied before the current scope ends.  Ie, if there is a "for each" function that iterates over some collection and evaluates your lambda then, once finished, returns.  If the lambda is going to be stored, capture usually by value, usually explicitly, and and never by reference implicitly.  In short, there are two species of lambda: the "temporary block" and the "persistent function object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These questions are somewhat subjective, but I'll give it a shot:

- Capture by reference when you need to modify the values in the enclosing scope (obviously), or when you want to avoid copying heavy variables; capture by value otherwise.
- Capture a specific variable by reference if you need to modify it's value in the enclosing scope, but not the values of other variables.
- I try to always specify the return type to increase readability (so other people can immediately know the return type, instead of having to parse the lambda to deduce it).
- The last one is the most subjective of all, but I personally think that lambdas bigger than ~3-5 lines should be refactored to functions, because long lambdas can reduce readability. However, there can be many exceptions, so this is rather a matter of personal preference and highly depends on the actual code.

Comment: For your last point, I'd like to say that it highly depend on the developer context. For instance, if you are using the [C++ Rest SDK](http://casablanca.codeplex.com), you're gonna deal with task and more precisely with `.then` where lambda will help readability of the code. ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj950083.aspx)) In that case having 10 lines for a lambda is more than acceptable, whereas having a named function will just pollute your class or namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Many of those questions have answers based on programmer's taste and his code style.

> When should you prefer to capture by reference [&] or value [=]? What are the performance implications?

You will capture by `&` when you want change the passed object or you don't want make a copy. Otherwise you can capture by `=`.

> When should you prefer to capture a variable explicitly, eg [&foo] ?

If you want just capture a specific object you use `[&foo]`, it's up to you to make your code more restrict by just passing specific object rather that `[&]` to avoid unintended mistakes.

> Under what circumstances should you specify a return type?

You will determine a return type (C++11) when you need it. There is no special thing to advise.

> How complex can a lambda be before it's better being rewritten as a function?

If you think a function are useful to be reused over many functions you should write it as 
a normal function. Lambdas usually are useful to solve a local requirement.

> Use a lambda whenever you need a simple predicate or comparator

Yes. The predicate or comparator functions where they will not be reused anymore are the popular case to use lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

For your last question:
A **lambda function** is essentially an anonymous function (a function without a name) that’s defined inline. It’s incredibly useful for when you need a small function that does not really seem to justify declaring and defining a normal function. The typical example where a lambda function is handy is for something like a comparison being passed to std::sort. For example:

```
struct Apple
{
   Apple(double weight, int age) :
      m_weight(weight),
      m_age(age)
   {}

   double m_weight; 
   int m_age; 
};

int main()
{
   vector<Apple> myApples;
   myApples.push_back(Apple(0.30, 30));
   myApples.push_back(Apple(0.75, 80));
   myApples.push_back(Apple(0.55, 90));

   sort(myApples.begin(),
        myApples.end(),
        [](const Apple &a, const Apple &b) -> bool
        {
           return (a.m_weight < b.m_weight);
        });

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers.

> Use a lambda whenever you need a simple predicate or comparator

Another useful pattern is to initialize `const` variables. Before lambdas, when initialization of a variable became too complex to fit in a single expression, you had either to drop the constness or write a separate function that is used only once (which has other problems, such as having to pass arguments from the original scope).

Consider the following dumb, extremely simplified example (*assume the initialization of `x` can't be rewritten as a single expression because the `if` part is too complex*):

```
void foo(int y) {
    int x = 42;
    if (y > 42)
        ++x;
    // from now on we mustn’t change x any more
    // but unfortunately it's not const
    // use x
}

// or

int init_x(int y) {
    // this function is only used once to initialize x in foo()
    // we could have many more parameters (not just y)
    int x = 42;
    if (y > 42)
        ++x;
    return x;
}
void foo(int y) {
    const int x = init_x(y);
    // use x
}
```

Now with lambdas you can get rid of both the additional function, parameter passing, and yet still keep the constness:

```
void foo(int y) {
    const int x = [&]() {
            int x = 42;
            if (y > 42)
                ++x;
            return x;
        }();
    //   ^^ note: we call the lambda immediately
    // use x
}
```

Of course this is still subject to the usual "rules" about whether we can write code inline or we should make a separate function. But this nicely solves those (many!) cases where the initialization code would be sufficiently complex to have to drop constness, but not complex enough to justify a separate function.